# Best way to create a gradient/blend like this one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm trying to create a blend similar to the one in the attached image. Would it have a better result in Photoshop or Illustrator, and what would be the best method?

[image: gradient]

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your intent (and preferences) .

***Especially* for print** I would use Illustrator.
If given the choice, always use vector, in my opinion.
It's definitely more  flexible (in terms of scaling at least), and using raster based graphics *may* result in a...  less smooth gradient/blend. 
For a result like your example above I would recommend Illustrator's Mesh Tool.
You can learn more about the Mesh Tool here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-growing-gradient-mesh-tomato.html

**Photoshop is not excluded.**
If you, like many people, are working mostly in Photoshop it's still an option.
You can get a nice result if you take your time. Try experiment with different soft brushes, maybe different blend modes etc.
But I would primarily use it for digital purposes.

Hope it helps!

Have fun :)

Comment: I agree with Tommy, Illustrator: Gradient Mesh. There are blogs out there on how to adjust meshes with stunning results.